# how to add datatable result from database to existing datagridview with existing header columns

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a `datagridview` and I defined a header columns (id, name, lastname etc..). In the data tear special class, I retrieve data from the database that returns the `DataTable` type, which I then pass to the `datagridview` as a result. When I do this, all existing datagridview header columns are deleted or new ones are just added from existing ones.

I want to achieve that only new rows are added to the existing grid and that the header columns remain.

**Here is how i get data from db:**

```
public DataTable SubjectList()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(DB.connString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select name, lastname from subjekti";
            using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                adapter.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
    }

    return dt;
}
```

And in form event on button click i want to load that result to existing grid

```
private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Data.SubjectRepository  data = new Data.SubjectRepository();

    datagridView1.DataSource  = data;       
}
```

The purpose of this is that when I open the form that displays the list of users, it is empty and has visible datagridview header columns. When I click on the search button, new rows should be added to the grid. It should not delete the existing header columns, it should only add them to the existing ones.

Comment: Set AutGenerateColums to false - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: the old and the new tables have the same number and names of columns?

Comment: use a binding source and when rows are added just use Add method of binding source

Comment: I have the some columns, when i set false to AutoGenerateColums i get empty rows